# Multiple Certificate import issue

Tags: java, security, glassfish, keytool

My application needs to talk to more than one secure servers.

I am using **keytool** to import the certificate.

Certificate import steps:

```
keytool -import -keystore aaa.jks -file aaa.co.uk.cer

keytool -import -keystore bbb.jks -file bbb.co.uk.cer
```

It works fine with one certificate but as soon as I import the second certificate the previous one stops working.

Error:

```
    Exception:javax.naming.CommunicationException: 
simple bind failed: aaa.co.uk:636 
[Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I also tried the following steps but it's still failing:

```
keytool -import -keystore aaa.jks -alias ms -file aaa.co.uk.cer

keytool -import -alias ms -file bbb.co.uk.cer
```

I think I should be appending the certificates in one keystore but don't know how to do it.

Any idea how to do it or am I missing something?

Env: Java 1.6
App Server: Glassfish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you import both certificates to the same alias ?

tell us the **keytool** command line you are using and what exactly 'stops working' after the second import.

Comment: @BN - thx for your suggestion. I already tried but it does not work unless I'm using wrong way? Plz see updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @BertNase for suggestion.

The following import command has fixed the issue:

```
keytool -import -keystore myStore.jks -alias aliasA -file aaa.co.uk.cer
keytool -import -keystore myStore.jks -alias aliasB -file bbb.co.uk.cer
```

Now, this command imports both certificates in the same **keystore**.